# An error occurred - Undefined offset: 0 : when I tried to install SiteCake

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I am trying to install [SiteCake](http://sitecake.com/install.html) to my basic website, the structure is as follows: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">

   <title>Index | Website Name</title>
   <meta content="" name="description">
   <link href="assets/elements/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
   <link href="assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="assets/css/tablet-and-mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--Libraries & Scripts-->

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--IE Support-->
   <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="index">

   <header id="header"><!--Header-->
      <div id="headerContent">
         <div id="headerLogo">
            <!--Logo--><a href=""><img alt="Website Name Logo" src="assets/elements/logo.png"></a>
         </div>
         <nav><!--Main Menu-->
            <ul id="mainMenu">
               <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </header>

   <div id="page"><!--Page Container-->

      <div class="topSection">
         <div class="content">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
         </div>
      </div>

      <!--Footer-->
      <footer id="footer">
         <div class="content">
            <div class="copyright">
               <p>©2014 Website Name. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </div><!--/Page-->
   <!--Scripts-->
   <script src="assets/js/form-validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed the instruction provided on SiteCake, by adding `<?php include "sitecake/server/sitecake_entry.php"; ?>` to the very top of the page... and once I did that, it shows this error:

```
An error occurred

Application error

Exception information:

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Stack trace:

#0 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php(142): Bootstrap::globalErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/clients/p...', 142, Array)
#1 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php(117): PageTemplateImpl->createTemplate()
#2 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php(34): PageTemplateImpl->initTemplateEngine()
#3 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/RenderServiceImpl.php(54): PageTemplateImpl->setPageRequest('/index.php')
#4 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/RenderServiceImpl.php(23): RenderServiceImpl->renderResponse()
#5 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/controllers/RenderController.php(13): RenderServiceImpl->render('/index.php', false)
#6 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): RenderController->renderAction()
#7 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('renderAction')
#8 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#9 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#11 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/sitecake_entry.php(47): Zend_Application->run()
#12 /home/clients/public_html/index.php(1): include('/home/clients/p...')
#13 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'render',
  'action' => 'render',
)
```

Which can be viewed live here: http://loai.directory.

The following is showen in the error.log:

```
[10-Apr-2014 11:29:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clients/public_html/index.php:2)' in /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/onesite/Bootstrap.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Bootstrap::globalErrorHandler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/home/clients/p...', 3, Array)
#1 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(3): header('Expires: Mon, 2...')
#2 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/View.php(108): include('/home/clients/p...')
#3 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(880): Zend_View->_run('/home/clients/p...')
#4 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Layout.php(796): Zend_View_Abstract->render('layout.phtml')
#5 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php(143): Zend_Layout->render()
#6 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/ in /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/onesite/Bootstrap.php on line 122
[10-Apr-2014 11:29:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clients/public_html/index.php:2)' in /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/onesite/Bootstrap.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Bootstrap::globalErrorHandler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/home/clients/p...', 3, Array)
#1 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(3): header('Expires: Mon, 2...')
#2 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/View.php(108): include('/home/clients/p...')
#3 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(880): Zend_View->_run('/home/clients/p...')
#4 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Layout.php(796): Zend_View_Abstract->render('layout.phtml')
#5 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php(143): Zend_Layout->render()
#6 /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/library/ in /home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/onesite/Bootstrap.php on line 122
[10-Apr-2014 07:43:04 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function href() in /home/clients/public_html/assets/includes/menu.inc on line 1
[10-Apr-2014 07:43:05 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function href() in /home/clients/public_html/assets/includes/menu.inc on line 1
```

**Attempting to fix the problem**, I tried to change the position of the include and add it somewhere within the body, I also tried to change include to include_once, and also tried to add the following snippet to the footer:

```
<?php
          include “extern_php_code.php”;
          echo render_footer();
      ?>
```

But nothing worked for me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the content of your question is not specific. it's very difficult to read everything. so it would be better if you reduce it just enough for us to understand your problem..

Comment: Thank you for your comment, please take a look now

Comment: post the code of `public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php` if its too big, post lines from 120 to 150

Comment: @NeilMartin - please view it here: http://codepad.org/uENS648f

Comment: How have you structured your project (directories, index.php, other pages.php)? If you have an index.php may be you can install sitecake in your index.php directory and add <?php include "sitecake/server/sitecake_entry.php"; ?> on top of index.php

Comment: that what I did @doydoy44 index.php have the include, but for example about.php does not and it works: http://loai.directory/about.php

Comment: try to replace 
`define( 'PHP_TEMPLATE', false );` by 
`define( 'PHP_TEMPLATE', true );` in `sitecake\server\config.php`

Answer (score 0):

Please check following file on line #142 it's the source of your error of undefined offset 0 might be possible that array is empty instead of having element at index 0

```
/home/clients/public_html/sitecake/server/application/services/impl/basic/PageTemplateImpl.php(142)
```

[see here](http://sitecake.com/using-php-in-templates.php)
And
[stack overflow quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623548/more-dynamic-page-with-sitecake)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your head tag is missing.
alter line 142 this way or else check for missing head tag

```
if(isset($head[0])){
    $head[0]->innertext .= '$$$#sc_header[{{}}]';
}
else {
    // head tag not found
}
```

Comment: I replaced it, not working - is the problem coming out from that file?

Comment: slightly modified above code `if(isset($head))` to `if(isset($head[0]))` . try this. if it still doesn't work, plz go through the code n tell me what file is it trying to load. because whatever file it is trying to load does not contain a head tag or the file isn't loading. also if the current error is gone and you're getting any other error, then update

Comment: Same problem, but I did not really play with the files, I basically downloaded them from Sitecake and uploaded them, didn't touch them